# How does Stack Overflow decide the related questions?

Tags: discussion, search, related-questions, research

I am working with Stack Overflow data for some research purposes. I was wondering if anybody knows how the website decides the related questions? There is one podcast from 2008 but I think they might have changed things since then.

Comment: Related, possible dup from MSE: [How are “related” questions selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20473/how-are-related-questions-selected)